# Input box that triggers function on keyword

Tags: javascript, inputbox

How do I code an input box, that triggers a certain function, if I enter "x" into this input box? (I am using HTML and JavaScript)

This is the code I tried:

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type " id="inputId_1"></input>

<button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>
</form>

<script>
function getInputValue() {
      let an = document.getElementById(inputId_1).value;
    
     if (an == "k") {
    document.getElementById("iftest") = "zero was entered";
}
</script>
<p id ="iftest">Hello</p>
```

Comment: `an = 0` is an assignment expression and will always result in `true`, you need to use `an == "x"`  for example to use for comparison. (where `x` is the value you are looking for)

Comment: @Peter Seliger, sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic approach that allows ***a custom match value*** introduces kind of a reusable component which is identified by its specific [`custom data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute and initialized via [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and/or [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

The initializing process is very basic and takes care of a component's event handling by adding a generically implemented [handler function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to each identified input-element.

The low level generic handler gets triggered by any [`input` value change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/InputEvent) and derives all necessary data from the passed [`event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#properties).

Both values the input element's `value` and the `match` value of an input element's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) will be [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)d before trying to figure out whether they match partially or not via [`value.includes(match)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

In both cases one is going to use the related HTML `output` element, in the former case one renders an error specific message in the latter one would clear the output.

```js
function handleTextInputMatch(evt) {
  const elmInput = evt.currentTarget;
  const elmOutput = elmInput.parentNode.querySelector('output');

  const value = elmInput.value.toLowerCase();
  const match = elmInput.dataset.match.toLowerCase();

  if (value.includes(match)) {

    elmOutput.textContent = elmInput.dataset.matchOutput;
  } else {
    elmOutput.textContent = '';
  }
}

function initialize() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-text-input-match] [data-match]')
    .forEach(elmInput =>
      elmInput.addEventListener('input', handleTextInputMatch)
    );
}

initialize();
```

```css
output { color: #c00; }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset data-text-input-match>
    <legend>
      no "XXX" in any case
    </legend>
    <input
      type="text"
      data-match="xxx"
      data-match-output="partially invalid input value"
    />
    <output></output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset data-text-input-match>
    <legend>
      no "Foo" in any case
    </legend>
    <input
      type="text"
      data-match="FOO"
      data-match-output="invalid character sequence"
    />
    <output></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `keyup` or `keydown` eventListeners for this particular scenario:

```js
function handleKeyUp(event) {
  if (event.key.toLowerCase() == "x") {
    console.log("x typed")
  }
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="handleKeyUp(event)">
```